# what's the fastest way to get a large volume of data from an Oracle database into Java objects

Tags: java, performance, oracle

What's the fastest way to get a large volume of data from an Oracle database into Java objects.

Are there any Oracle tricks as to the way the data should be organised?

I was thinking of using plain JDBC rather than any Hibernate style libraries?

Would it be better to get Oracle to produce a file and then read from the file - although this has to be done programatically.

All thoughts appreciated.

Comment: I think I would setup a multi-threaded JDBC client to read batches of data.  Are you looking to serialize the java objects or are you just keeping them in memory?

Comment: I doubt you can write a JDBC library that will beat the performance of Hibernate. Make sure to define appropriate indexes on all tables you intend to access.

Comment: When you mean large volume of data , how much is it ? You want the entire data to be converted to java objects at one shot ? you may also need to check the heap size if you are planning to load everything at once

Comment: @Perception, wow.  We have a large scale production server product that was based on Hibernate for several years.  Ultimately, scalability drove us off.  Hibernate (and any JPA) generates some tremendously ridiculous queries.  Hand written SQL can perform several orders of magnitude better.  If you're inserting or retrieving a flat object from one table, maybe Hibernate can (nearly) match hand written SQL, but once you throw collections into the mix, forget it.  It's fine for applications which basically CRUD stuff ppl type into forms and jam into the DB, but not serious data processing.

Comment: I second the questions along the lines of "how fast?" and "how much?".  Are the applications co-located on the same box, etc.  The question needs more detail before you can get good answers.

Comment: @brettw - My answer is as generic as the OP's question. Quite obviously the way you structure your entities will have a ***HUGE*** impact on performance. Most naive implementations of nested collections utilize eagerly fetched SELECT's, when lazy fetched BATCH calls or SUBSELECTs would have significantly improved performance.

Comment: How much (in rows, volume) ? How fast ? I heave database with 4 billions rows and transfer 10 000row/sek (database size is 20G). In other database i have 100 000 rows (database size is 1TB) max transformation is 1 row/min.

Comment: This is an interesting question, please explain more what exactly is your problem, the question/answer will be very helpful to all of us.

Comment: To give a few more details.
The database will not be co-located. It will be in a data centre - nothing I can do about that.
We might be talk about 1 million rows - thet are to be kept in memory not serialised.

Comment: where is your bottleneck right now?  ru just asking Oracle for data from a simple select (select blah from table) or doing some crazy joins, or what?  To make the process faster, we'd need to know where your perf issues are today

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not a Java or JDBC expert, but if you plan on pulling a lot of rows down from a database, you will likely benefit by increasing the prefetch rows on the connection.

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:oracle:","user","password"); 

//Set the default row prefetch setting for this connection 
((OracleConnection)conn).setDefaultRowPrefetch(100);
```

I believe the default for JDBC is to fetch one row at a time, so you're paying for a round trip to the database for each row fetched.  (Note, I've seen documentation that suggests the default is 10 rows per round trip).  Setting prefetch to a larger number will fetch more rows per round trip to the database.  Speed increases can be dramatic depending on the number of rows and the performance of your network.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how far you want to go with this I'd imagine dropping jdbc and writing a custom application residing on the same machine as the DB using [Oracle Call API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/oci/index-090820.html) and JNI would be the fastest...

It's probably much simpler to just use a plain prepared statment using JDBC and then if that's not enough (and depending on where the bottle neck is) try making a stored procedure. The caching done by ORM's like Hibernate should not be discounted though, so I guess you'd have to do some benchmarks. Also if the bottle neck is the database and you write a stored procedure which improves the read performance, then you could still use Hibernate to marshal the data to java objects. See [Using stored procedures for querying](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#sp_query)

Comment: Do you have any evidence to back up the claim that using the Oracle API would be faster than plain JDBC?

Comment: I'm not interested in caching - onl;y in getting the data into Java memory.

Comment: @Emil H, caching won't help for reading data that has never been read before.

Comment: @Dan beyond the general statement that each layer in an application degrades performance, not realy. That's why the vague wording "I'd imagine" ;) That said there is a jdbc driver which uses the OCI (as oposed to the thin driver), but in recent versions there appears to be practically no perfomance difference between them and Oracle recomends using the thin driver even... I still suspect using the Oracle Call API directly would be the fastest way, but I admitt I haven't got the numbers to back this up :/

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you wind up doing, design for/implement "lazy initialization" [really only applies for complex object hierarchies/networks; you said java objects (plural) so I'm imagining something more than just a single table that maps to a single object].  So basically, you are only reading in the objects that are needed at that time; when you run a getter method, then it does more db calls for just that data.

Another trick sometimes overlooked in the Java world is: if you have some complex sql coming from the code, you can rather create a view on the Oracle side, embedding that complexity there, then map your object to the view; so if you can flatten your object like the view, then you're in business.